# mysql procedure list that contains a particular column

Tags: mysql

I need the list of all the procdures which contain the name of a column.

**Example**

I have database- `mydb`

column name: `mycolumn`

procedures that contain the column

```
1. SP_procedure1
2. SP_procedure2
3. SP_procedure3
```

I need a query that will give me this list when I specify the column name and database name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' 
AND routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
AND ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%mycolumn%'
```

This will give the results

Answer (score 0):

I think this gives a more accurate result set

```
SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM information_schema.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'mydb' 
AND routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
AND ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%mtablename%' // here is the extra code
and ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%mycolumn%'
```